# W/dalvikvm(16493): Bogus method descriptor: void (V)

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

Ok, I'm getting a Bogus method descriptor from my JNI code. 
I'm trying to get my class constructor method ID, and it's just not playing ball. 
I have also tried, (void) V ,
(V)V , (void) void

None of which works,
However when I set an Int param and put a (I)V method descriptor, it works? but passing in an unused uneeded param is messy.
I copied and pasted the method descriptor from the official JNI specification, I don't know why it doesn't work.

EDIT : And I'm doing the correct "" method name to...

Here's my C++ :

```
jmethodID methHelperContructor = env->GetMethodID(javaHelperClass, "<init>", "void (V)");
```

Here's my Java :

```
Gameplay3DHelper(){};
```

Comment: It should just be `()V` I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how to best piece this together other than just running a sample Java class through `javah` yourself and reading the comments.

I think if you take [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) and [this JNI documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html) together, make the connection between Java and Android, and then shake it a little, you might conclude that the correct type signature is `()V`, for "takes no arguments, returns void".

Comment: Thanks. I actually got the "bogus" method descriptor from the original JNI documentation.